# Reload once content is loaded, Loading animation?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic for just a simple tab app that displays some info I load from an external source (in this case parse). It works pretty well, although sometimes I am noticing that I click a view and the view will be blank. When I tap the tab again it populates the list with the view from the server. I am assuming this is the app taking a momment to load the data.. it seems to take less than a second, but dosen't then update.

Has anyone seen this? I was thinking I could probably just build some sort of loading thing that shows? Is there an easy solution to basically refresh the view once the content has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Boolean controller variable in your controller, when everything loaded and all promises resolved set it to true

In your view wrap everything in ... Ng-if='controller.loading===true'

You could also create another div that says ... Ng-if loading===false 
And inside it put a loading icon

Remember to initialise controller variable to false initially

Comment: Hmm still does the same thing..i have to re-click the tab to reload it

Comment: ok that behaviour is not normal, i suggest you try and narrow down the issue. remove logic from your app bit by bit and see what fixes the issue